# store tableview data into an array

Tags: iphone

I have made an iphone application, in which I have put tableview , the data in tableview is added by selecting datetime picker ,whenever we select any date time from picker it will get add into the tableview. Now I want to put all these added value of datetime into an array.

how can I do this. I am searching this concept from last many days. But got no answer. Please if some one know, help me.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

`NSMutableArray` is what you'll want. It provides a method called `addObject:`, so you can add these date values to your array with ease.

**Edit:** You asked for an example, very well. Here's how you can do it and how **you** should approach such problems in the future:

1) You said you had a `UIDatePicker` instance that you wanted to save the date of. So how do we get the date? The first thing you should **always** do is consult the Apple Developer Documentation, in this case for [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html). A short read reveals that this class has a **date** property.

Aah `UIDatePicker`, is there anything you can't do?

Now that we have the date we want, you'll want to put it into an `NSMutableArray`, as I have suggested. So we do it the same way again - open the Apple Developer Documentation and look up [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That reveals to us that there is in fact a `addObject:` method but wait...**there's more??** Yep, `NSMutableArray` is damn powerful, so have a look through the ***entire*** document and see what you can use.

The documentation reveals that we can use `addObject:` to add an object to the array, so let's start:

`NSMutableArray*myDates = [NSMutableArray array];`

Now we've initalised our array. Now let's add an object:

`[myDates addObject:[datePicker date]];`

Done. We've now added an object. If you want to save this disc at a later stage, use `NSMutableArray`'s `writeToFile:atomically:` method. For more details, read the documentation.

Now don't just go ahead and copy and paste the code. Read Apple's documents on these classes, they are really helpful and will enable you to resolve such problems in the future.

Comment: how can i implement this, please give me some example.

Comment: I have added an explanation for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you add date in table view, add the same date to an array. 
take an array in .h and then add date to array

`[arr addObject:date];`